# How to find the object with smallest related_set in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a djano model:

```
class Expiration(models.Model):
    UNIT_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Month'),
        ('W', 'Week')
    )
    unit    =   models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices= UNIT_CHOICES)
    number_of_units = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    offset = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Profile(models.Model):
    name          = models.CharField(default="tmp", max_length=32, blank=True)
    expiration_period = models.ForeignKey(Expiration, blank=True, null=True)
```

What I need to do is to fetch that instance of Expiration that has the smallest number of Profiles associated with it and in case of duplicate, return one of them. Or better say if `exp` is an instance of Expiration, I am looking for the `exp` with smallest `exp.profile_set.count()`

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#) your query set with the number of profiles for each expiration. Then order by the annotated field. The profile with the fewest (or joint fewest) profiles is the first result of the query set.

Putting it all together, you have:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Expiration.objects.annotate(num_profiles=Count('profile')).order_by('num_profiles')[0]
```